# Android drawable importer - Not shown under settings

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-drawable-importer

i need to import some drawables in different sizes, in my App.

So i've tried to install Android Drawable Importer.

My problem is now, that i dont have a entry under Settings (installed the Plugion over the Pluginmanager and restarted Android Studio after)

Someone of you, know what to do?

[image: Under Tools is no other point like "Other settings"]

Comment: I unfortunately do not know what to do. But I advise you to study [Android Asset Studio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio). Maybe this will help you to replace the a plugin. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I also do not have these settings ( anymore ) - I think the drawable-importer got rid of settings and now just works. Note also how it is used has now changed ( not multiple entry-points for the different sources anymore which is a good thing ) - I was stumbeling over this recently - but now like this new behavior